# Socket server in-memory representation: Sqlite in-memory table or Array?

Tags: php, sqlite, sockets, memory

I am writing a socket server in php to allow flash games to communicate with each other. I have to take care about the users and their properties (points, location, message, etc.), the rooms, games. And their connections.

First I made it with OOP and stored the connections in arrays of references (with & operator).

But now I considering to rewrite with sqlite in-memory table as backend for data.

Do you have any pro or contra any of the two solutions?

Comment: Why are you considering the rewrite to begin with?

Comment: It hard to maintain, and debug the arrays of references. An the current OOP implementation got to be too big, well I mean I think I am better in relation databases and have a bigger experience. Now I just considering performance and scalability. Well beacuse it's in PHP it is only single threaded, which decrease the level of scalability.